# Get child pages in java component xwiki

Tags: java, xwiki

I'm trying to get all the documents that list the current document as the perant using:

```
 List<DocumentReference>  childDocs = doc.getChildrenReferences(xcontext);
```

where doc is the parent XWikiDocument.

However the function only return an empty list, althoug there is documents in the space.

If I print doc.getFullName() its AAA.WebHome.. And all the chldren spaces is listed under AAA.. how should I reference doc to get say AAA.BBB.WebHome in the list? or where am I going wrong?

I'm trying ot write a recursive function that deletes all the child pages in the current space. But can't list all the child pages. Here is the recursive function:

```
public void RECdeleteSpace(XWikiDocument doc, XWikiContext xcontext,boolean toTrash){
      XWiki xwiki = xcontext.getWiki();
      List<DocumentReference> childDocs;
      try {
            childDocs = doc.getChildrenReferences(xcontext);
            System.out.println("REC " + doc.getFullName());
            System.out.println("CHLD " + childDocs.toString());
            System.out.println("----- ");
            Iterator<DocumentReference> docit = childDocs.iterator();
            while (docit.hasNext()) {
                DocumentReference chdocref = docit.next();
                XWikiDocument  chdoc = xwiki.getDocument(chdocref, xcontext);
                System.out.println("DOC: "+chdoc.getFullName());

                RECdeleteSpace(chdoc,xcontext,toTrash);  
            }
          xwiki.deleteDocument(doc, toTrash, xcontext);

      } catch (XWikiException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }
```

The output is only:

```
INIT WebHome
REC AAA.WebHome
CHLD []
-----
```

And the itterator is nver going to AAA.BBB.Webhome or AAA.BBB.CCC.WebHome

Comment: Which XWiki version is this? I tried with 7.3 but could not reproduce. (Also some random idea: is the page `BBB` marked as hidden?)

Comment: Another idea to try: what does `doc.isNew()` produce? If a non-existing document is accessed, this does not produce a `null` but a document is created in the fly, for which `isNew()` returns `true`.  Such a "not yet existing" document has no children of course. Happened to me because I resolved a path in the wrong context ...

Comment: The problem was caused by the page creation component which did not set the page parent on creation. So the child reference was never set. When the parent was set for all documents the function worked fine.